# Typecast operator overload with as nonmember function

Tags: c++, overloading

Is it possible to define the typecast operator as a non-member global
function?

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                                                                                                                      
#include <stdlib.h>                                                                                                                                                     

typedef int hash_t;                                                                                                                                                     

struct wrap {                                                                                                                                                           
    int v;                                                                                                                                                              
    operator hash_t () {                                                                                                                                                
        hash_t h = v+1;                                                                                                                                                 
        return h;                                                                                                                                                       
    }                                                                                                                                                                   
};                                                                                                                                                                      

int main(int argc, char **argv) {                                                                                                                                       
    int v = 1;                                                                                                                                                          
    hash_t h = (hash_t)wrap{v};                                                                                                                                         
    printf("%d\n", h);                                                                                                                                                  
    return 0;                                                                                                                                                           
}
```

Instead of `(hash_t)wrap{v}` being able to write `(hash_t)v` would be helpful. Not shure how the syntax of the overload would be, but something like `operator hash_t (int v) { ... }` ? Or is the typecast operator only overloadable in with memberfunction of a class/struct?

I want to define a dictionary `template <typename key> CDict` and want to convert key to int to use it as a hash. But I dont want to dispatch the hash function depending on the type of key or use a virtual function and also be able to use int as type for key.... Instead I want to overload the (hash_t) typecast.
Is this possible with global typecast overloads (or dont they exits) ?

Comment: afaik you cannot overload any operator for `int`. Whats wrong with `hash_t just_pick_a_different_name(int v)` ?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here.  You can make a free function that does the conversion if you want: https://godbolt.org/g/MTSE74

Comment: `hash_t` and `int` are synonyms, so that's a very roundabout way of writing `int h = v + 1;`. Do you have a more realistic use case?

Comment: @molbdnilo: I want to define a dictionary ``` template <typename key> CDict``` and want to convert ```key``` to int to use it as a hash. But I dont want to dispatch the hash function depending on the type of key or use a virtual function and also be able to use int as type for  key.... Instead I want to overload the (hash_t) typecast for each type.

Comment: @KonradEisele why not just write a free hash function that you overload for the different types?

Comment: @RyanHaining: Ok, thats. Thats maybe a way to go. Still, just from the language point of view, is there something like ```global typecast overloads``` or whatever they might be called ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems what you actually want to do is call different functions depending on the type, the operator overload is not the right way to go about this.

Instead, you can create a free function to handle `int` specifically, and then delegate to a member function in the non-int case

```
using hash_type = int;

// handle int
hash_type my_hash(int i) {
  return i;
}

// handle anything else
template <typename T>
hash_type my_hash(const T& t) {
  return t.hash(); // use whatever pattern you want here
}

template <typename Key, typename Value>
struct CDict {
  void insert(const Key& k, const Value& v) {
    auto hash = my_hash(k); // calls correct overload
  }
};

// a type with a hash member function
struct MyHashable {
  hash_type hash() const {
    return 0;
  }
};

int main() {
  CDict<int, double> c1;
  c1.insert(3, 5.0);

  CDict<MyHashable, char> c2;
  c2.insert(MyHashable{}, 'a');
}
```

Don't create type names ending with `_t`, [they are reserved](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Reserved-Names.html)

Comment: They are [reserved in the global namespace by POSIX as an extension to the C standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html). If you're not targeting a POSIX system or if you're not working in the global namespace, they're fine.